# Balls in bins with minimum spacing between filled bins

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say we have *n* identical balls and a row of *m* identical bins (with *n*<*m*). Say that the balls must be placed in the bins such that:

- No bin has more than one ball, and
- There are at least *j* empty bins between each two consecutive filled bins.

Assume that the values of *n*, *m*, and *j* are such that there is at least one configuration of balls in bins that will satisfy these requirements. Suppose that, of all such configurations, we choose one randomly, and place the balls accordingly.

Now suppose someone has to guess which *n* bins contain a ball. Assuming they also randomly choose a configuration that would satisfy the requirements, what is the probability that they would correctly pick at least *k* filled bins?